# Matching documents that contain a string array where at least one of the array elements is not an empty string

Tags: arrays, mongodb, filter

I have documents that contain simple arrays of strings, and I can't seem to set up a filter that is capable of bringing back all documents where a given array field has at least one element string that is not "". This is on a collection with 6500 documents, where 3700 should meet the above criteria (I checked by pulling all records and performing the filter client-side).

I am mainly using the driver in .NET, but I've also tinkered with the filter in Compass. Using the driver I've tried Ne, Not(Eq), AnyNe, Not(AnyEq), Nin[""], Not(In[""]). I would like to use ElemMatch, but it seems like that is geared towards arrays of documents not arrays of strings, since you have to specify a field name, which doesn't exist in this case. I've also tried setting up a .Where filter that looped through to find any non-empty string in the array, but it threw an exception at run-time (I'm coding in VB).

```
Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.AnyNe(Of String)("field", String.Empty)
```

I would expect that the above filter, where "field" is a reference to an array of strings, would bring back 3700 documents but I get 0.

I would imagine that I'm clearly the one missing something here, as this does not seem like it should be a difficult query/filter to construct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone as confused as I am:

I mentioned earlier that ElemMatch seems to be geared for arrays of documents, but apparently if you forgo using the Builder classes and type out the query manually you can actually use ElemMatch within .NET to query a simple String Array field where at least one entry is not empty string "".

Correct/Working example: {"[array_field_name]": {$elemMatch: {$ne: ""}}}

If anyone can tell me how to create that example using the Builder classes, that'd be awesome.